# How to turn the display off via commandline on Ubuntu 18.04+?

Tags: 18.04, display, suspend, 20.04, acpi

Years ago, probably on 16.04, I was able to turn the display off via `xset dpms force off` (and a small `sleep` before).

In the last years, I think since 18.04, that doesn't work anymore. The display itself goes to sleep, however, it wakes up after a few seconds.

For general information, when I lock the screen (which, in this case, I *don't* want to), it goes to sleep stably after a certain time.

What's happening? Is there any way to send the display to sleep via commandline (without locking)?

Comment: `sleep 3; xset dpms force off` try this.

Comment: Also, try this. It is probably not what you are looking for though. https://www.howtogeek.com/61836/how-to-turn-off-your-monitor-with-a-hotkey-in-ubuntu/ You can execute the file through terminal if you want. Tell me how you go.

Comment: _`sleep 3; xset dpms force off` try this._ this is not really relevant - I'm already invoking a small `sleep`, as explained

Comment: _Also, try this. It is probably not what you are looking for though. https://www.howtogeek.com/61836/how-to-turn-off-your-monitor-with-a-hotkey-in-ubuntu_ Thanks! This actually worked, or, to be more specific, it was crucial for pinpointing the cause to the screensaver. I've solved the problem by simply inhibiting it at startup, since I only need locking functionality, no screensaver!

Comment: Glad to be a help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the screensaver.

In cases where the screensaver is not needed (but only the screen locking functionality), inhibiting it will solve the problem, for example:

```
cat > ~/.config/autostart/inhibit_screen_saver.desktop << EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Inhibit screensaver
Exec=bash -c 'while ! pgrep mate-screensave; do sleep 1; done; mate-screensaver-command -i'
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
EOF
```

A wait cycle is needed to make sure that mate-screensaver executes. It's not clear to me however, why pgrep finds `mate-screensave`, but not `mate-screensaver`.